# apply-BootMedia.cmd DISM.exe version

Tags: windows-7-x64, intel-galileo, windowsondevices

can anyone point me in the direction of the correct version of DISM.exe for Windows 7 SP1 to create the Intel Galileo Boot SD ?

The version shown is the current version on my Laptop which seem like it is incorrect as it fails due to unsupported command line switch used inside the 'apply-BootMedia.cmd'

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.1.7600.16385

Comment: Found it the version 6.3.9600.1729 works and is part of the Windows Deployment with the Windows ADK

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem writing the image on Windows 7.
You need to try the version from Windows 8.1. That worked for me.